# HTML Picture and header alignment trouble

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm having trouble getting things in the right place on my website using HTML and CSS. I am very new to coding in these languages as I only learnt them yesterday.

This is the code I have: [My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gy6K/1030/)

```
    <h1 class="jumbotron"><img class="logo" src="logo2.jpg"/>My website</h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a style="border-top 1px solid #bbb" class="active"    href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The picture on the left just above the Home button is what I am having trouble with, I want to move up as only half of it is showing. I want it to fit in the top left corner square.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, here is edited code to make the picture placed in top left.

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A few tweaks to some of my code and it fits great.

Comment: Great! Remember to check the answer as helpful